# Passing pointers through for loops and if statements

Tags: c, pointers, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to pass a pointer through this for loop but it doesn't work. This is just a block from my original code. I didn't want to overload you all with 200 lines of code! If you need all of it please ask.

Ok! so I used 3 printf's to see how far my code gets before it crashes. It gets to the printf( "2" ); before it crashes. So I am assuming it is something to do with `if ( *(userInput + i ) == sNumArray[j] )`  I am not sure what I am doing wrong. As far as I know pointers dont use pointer[i] to cycle through each element they use `*( pointer + i )` ?

I only started programming with C 4 weeks ago so sorry if I didn't explain this thoroughly. I am still learning the terminology etc

```
for ( i = 0; i < sUserInput_SIZE; i++ ) {

    printf( "1" );

    for ( j = 0; j < sNumArray_SIZE; j++ ) {

        printf( "2" );

        if ( *(userInput + i) == sNumArray[j] ) {

            validInput++;
            printf( "3" );

        }//End if( )

    }//End inner for( )

}//End outer for( )
```

Here is my source code
I am trying to create a function that checks if what the user inputted is a number or not. The main code is an atm that will allow the user to enter in a their pin, change their pin and see how many times the pin was entered in correctly.

I know you can error check with the isdigit function but I wanted to try make my own function for it for learning purposes and I have spent way to much time on this and I am to stubborn to let it go to try something else.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define sUserInput_SIZE 5
#define sNumArray_SIZE 10


char * errorChecking( char *userInput ) {

    //VARIABLE LIST
    //Note: Each variable will have the alphabetical character associated with its data structure at the beginning of its name e.g. integer data structures will have the charater "i" at the beginning of the variable etc
    //Outer for loop variable
    unsigned i;
    //Inner for loop variable
    unsigned j;
    // validInput will be compared with strlen( ) function which is an unsigned int........more?
    unsigned iValidInput = 0;

    //ARRAY LIST

    //This array will be used to check each inputed character to check if it is a number
    char sNumArray[sNumArray_SIZE] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };

    //End of Declarations


    //This for loop will cross reference each element the user inputed with the number array
    for ( i = 0; i < sUserInput_SIZE; i++ ) {

        for( j = 0; j < sNumArray_SIZE; j++ ) {

            if ( *(userInput + i ) == sNumArray[j] ) {

                //Every time a number is successfully verified as a number the "validInput" variable will be incremented by 1 
                iValidInput++;

            }//End if( )

        }//End inner for( )

    }//End outer for( )


    //This if statement will check if the inputed value is an integer or not by checking if the number of valid inputs equalls the length of the sUserInput array
    if ( validInput == strlen( userInput ) ){

        printf( "\n\nIs a integer" );
        return( userInput)

    }//End if( )
    else {
        printf( "\n\nIs " );
        printf( "\n\nError: This is not a integer \nTry again: " );
        scanf("%s" , &userInput );


    }//End else



    return( userInput );

}//End main( )

//FIX ME: only add convert it input is verified
//FIX ME: Loop back around if it is not a number

int main( ) {

    //VARIABLE LIST
    //Note: Each variable will have the alphabetical character associated with its data structure at the beginning of its name e.g. integer data structures will have the charater "i" at the beginning of the variable etc

    int iExitLoop = 1;
    unsigned int iCorrectInputs = 0;
    unsigned int iIncorrectInputs = 0;
    char *iNewUserPin = "0";
    char *iUserPin = "1234";
    char *sUserInput = "1";


    //End of Declarations


    while ( iExitLoop == 1 ) {

        //Main menu
        printf( "\n1: Enter pin" );
        printf( "\n2: Change pin" );
        printf( "\n3: Successful and unsuccessful pin logs" );
        printf( "\n4: Exit" );
        printf( "\n\n%s" , sUserInput );

        //Prompting the user to entered in an option
        printf( "\n\nEnter: " );
        scanf( "%s" , &sUserInput );
        printf( "%s" , *sUserInput);

        //Prompting user to enter pin
        if ( strncmp( sUserInput , "1" , 1 ) != 0 ) {

            //This do while loop will prompt the user to enter in their pin and keep running until the correct pin is entered
            do {
                printf( "\nPlease enter your pin: " );
                scanf( "%s" , &sUserInput );
                errorChecking( sUserInput );

                if ( sUserInput == iUserPin ) {
                    iCorrectInputs++;
                }//End if( )
                else {
                    iIncorrectInputs++;
                    printf( "\nTry again!" );
                }//End else
            } while ( sUserInput != iUserPin );//End Do While( )
            //FIX ME - ADD ERROR CHECKING ( FUNCTIONS? )

        }//End if( )


        //Prompting user to change their pin
        if ( sUserInput == "2" ) {

            do {
                printf( "\nPlease enter you current pin: " );
                scanf( "%s" , &sUserInput );
                //FIX ME - ADD ERROR CHECKING ( FUNCTIONS? )

                if ( sUserInput != iUserPin ) {
                    printf( "\nIncorrect pin!" );
                }//End if( )

            } while ( sUserInput != iUserPin );//End do while( )


            while ( iNewUserPin != iUserPin ) {

                printf( "\nEnter new pin: " );
                scanf( "%s" , &iNewUserPin );

                printf( "Re-enter new pin: " );
                scanf( "%s" , &iUserPin );

                if ( iNewUserPin != iUserPin ) {

                    printf( "\nTry again!" );

                }//End if( )

            }//End while( ) 

        }//End if( )


        //This block of code will the display the amount of correct and incorrect inputs
        if ( sUserInput == "3" ) {

            printf( "\nYour pin was correctly entered %d times" , iCorrectInputs );
            printf( "\nYour pin was incorrectly entered %d times" , iIncorrectInputs );

        }//End if( )

        //This block of code will end the program if the user inputs 4
        //FIX ME: possibly use sUserInput for loop execution
        if ( sUserInput == "4" ) {

            iExitLoop = 0;

        }//End if( )

    }//End while( )

    return( 0 );

}//End main( )


//FIX ME: error checking for 4 character input
```

Comment: Your output is flawed, because you do not flush the output buffer. That means you could have lots of output buffered and the crash happens somewhere else unrelated to where you think it is. Always end your `printf` strings with a newline (`"\n"`), that flushes the buffer.

Comment: And you should also learn how to use a debugger. If you run your program in a debugger it will stop when the crash happens, showing you the location of it. If the crash is not in your code, then you can go up the call stack until you are at your code. Then you can examine variables and see their values.

Comment: Regarding your confusion about accessing like this `pointer[i]`. This is correct for both array as well as pointer. `[]` subscript operator can be used for pointer as well as arrays.

Comment: Regarding the comment by @ameyCU, for any pointer *or* array `a` and valid index `i` the expression `a[i]` is *equal* to `*(a + i)`.

Comment: Post the definitions of `sNumArray`, `sNumArray_SIZE`, `userInput` and `sUserInput_SIZE`.  Indeed, post a complete compilable program.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing inherently wrong with the code fragment you posted.  Indeed `*(userInput + i)` is exactly equivalent to `userInput[i]`.  You probably have a consistency issue with the array sizes.

Note that you use `userInput` and `sUserInput_SIZE`: the names are inconsistent. You might have 2 different arrays `userInput` and `sUserInput` and these might have different sizes?

**EDIT**:

From the full source code, it appears `sUserInput` is a pointer to a 1 character string `"i"`. Accessing bytes from this pointer beyond offset `1` invokes undefined behavior. Since you are dealing with a character string, instead of iterating until `sUserInut_SIZE`, you should just test for the null terminator:

```
for (i = 0; userInput[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < sNumArray_SIZE; j++) {
        if (userInput[i] == sNumArray[j]) {
            validInput++;
        }
    }
}
```

You could compute the length of `userInput` first and use the length as the upper bound of the loop and as the value to compare the final `validInput` to.

There are more problems in the rest of the code:

- your error handling code does not check the second entry for validity.
- More important: the `scanf()` to read `sUserInput` in `main()` is incorrect. You should use:

  ```
  char sUserInput[20];

  if (scanf("%19s", sUserInput) == 1) {
      /* handle sUserInput */
  } else {
      /* premature end of file? */
  }
  ```
- Your comparison `if (strncmp(sUserInput , "1" , 1) != 0)` is incorrect, you should check `== 0` as the return value of `strncmp()` and `strcmp()` is `0` it the (sub)strings are equal.
- You cannot compare strings with `==`: `if (sUserInput == "2")` should be changed to `if (strcmp(sUserInput, "2") == 0)`
- Similarly, `if ( sUserInput == iUserPin )` is incorrect.  Use `strcmp()` for this too.

Comment: userInput is the functions argument and sUserInput_SIZE is a #define size . I have posted the full code. Just ignore the "FIX ME:" comments they are just notes to myself.

Comment: @C.Centre: see my updated answer